Multiple virtual routers on a single machine
As part of a production line, I need to test that a device is able to connect to the internet through its ethernet port.
Each device will have a unique set of:

static IP/netmask
static gateway IP
DNS server IPs (main and fallback)
NTP server IP

All sets of these settings can be known ahead of time, but not which set is being used by the device currently being tested.
I would like a box with two ethernet ports. One going to the device under test, the other going to the company router for internet access (ideally configured with DHCP). Performance is not that important.
So far I'm thinking of creating a bridge that holds:

the two ethernet interfaces
veth pairs bound to a dns and ntp server running locally on the box

What I'm struggling to understand is how to set up nftables to route connections to their appropriate destination (dns/ntp traffic should get routed to the local servers, traffic to the gateway should get routed through whatever gateway is configured by DHCP)
EDIT: example scenario as requested.
I have two devices under test(DUTs) with the following properties:

Device 1

Static IP/netmask: 192.168.0.123/24
Static gateway IP: 192.168.0.100
DNS server IPs:    192.168.0.101, 192.168.0.102
NTP server IP:     192.168.0.103


Device 2

Static IP/netmask: 172.16.0.123/12
Static gateway IP: 172.16.0.100
DNS server IPs:    172.16.0.101, 172.16.0.102
NTP server IP:     172.16.0.103



I need a box that I can plug in between the DUT and my main router that will have DNS/NTP servers listening on all the server IPs above and forward traffic (NAT?) destined for their gateways to my real gateway which is a 10.x address. As a bonus the servers should only be served to connections coming in through the DUT connection, but it's not that big of a deal if they end up accessible on the main network.

Traffic will be routed appropriately based on the target ip address. What you've described should "just work" without any particular netfilter rules, unless there are details that are missing from this question.

@larsks are you saying to create a veth pair for every possible IP that I need to service?
What happens for packets that are destined for the internet with a gateway that doesn't exist? Wouldn't I need some routing rule to route it through my one internet interface?

It's possible I am failing to understand your question. I'm certainly not suggesting anything about veth interfaces. I'm partly confused because you're asking about routing, but you've created a bridge, and you indicate you have an external router. Maybe you could update your question with a specific scenario that you're not sure how to support?

@larsks example added, hopefully it's more clear to you

Based on the description in your question, you have an environment something like this:
                                      ┌─────────┐
                                      │         │
                                    ┌─┤ device1 │ (192.168.0.123)
           ┌─────────┐   ┌───────┐  │ │         │
           │         │   │       │  │ └─────────┘
internet ──┤ gateway ├───┤ mitm  ├──┤            
           │         │   │       │  │ ┌─────────┐
           └─────────┘   └───────┘  │ │         │
           10.10.0.1                └─┤ device2 │ (172.16.0.123)
                                      │         │
                                      └─────────┘

We're going to focus on the mitm node. We'll assume that eth0 is the "internal" interface to which device1 and device2 are connected, while eth1 is connected to your external gateway.
Using the specific example from your question, we would configure eth0 on mitm with several addresses: the default route, DNS, and ntp addresses for each of device1 and device2.
When we're done, the interface configuration on mitm looks like this:
mitm:/# ip addr show
2: eth0@if342: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1e:ad:8f:3f:aa:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.0.100/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 172.16.0.100/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.101/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 172.16.0.101/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.102/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 172.16.0.102/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.103/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 172.16.0.103/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1cad:8fff:fe3f:aa93/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
343: eth1@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:b0:c2:e4:53:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet 10.10.0.10/24 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::40b0:c2ff:fee4:534f/64 scope link proto kernel_ll
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And for completeness, the routing table on mitm looks like:
mitm:/# ip route
default via 10.10.0.1 dev eth1
10.10.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.0.10
172.16.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.100
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.100

We need to add a MASQUERADE rule for traffic egressing mitm to your gateway, since the gateway won't know how to route traffic back to your internal networks:
mitm:/# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

Assuming that you're running a dns server (e.g. dnsmasq) and an ntp server (e.g. chrony) on mitm, everything should Just Work:

Traffic from e.g. device1 to the internet will first go to device1's default gateway (192.168.0.100), which is...mitm. From there it will go to gateway (after masquerading), and then on to the wide, wide world.

DNS requests from device1 will go to the appropriate DNS servers, 192.168.0.101 and/or 192.168.0.102...which are mitm.

NTP requests from device1 will go to 192.168.0.103...which is mitm.


And similarly for traffic from device2.
No bridges, no veth interfaces; just basic routing.

I put together a script to simulate this environment that I used to validate this answer; you can find it here if you are curious.

Note that with this configuration, other systems on the 10.x.x.x network will be able to access services on mitm. You have several options for preventing this:

You could configure services on mitm to bind explicitly to the internal addresses (dnsmasq -a 192.168.0.101 -a 192.168.0.102 ...)
You could add firewall rules to block access on eth.

Pick whatever works for you.

I wonder if in some cases, replies from the DNS server and NTP server could have a "wrong" source IP (namely the corresponding "first" / "gateway" IP), especially if the transport protocol is UDP. In case that happens, perhaps it could be worked around by having REDIRECT rules for all possible DNS / NTP IPs...

By the way, at least as per the example in the post, "Device 2" could have any IP from within the whole /12 block...

The address of device2 shouldn't impact anything here (as long as it falls within a distinct network from device1). I'm not sure whether we would see any issues involving wrong source addresses; certainly nothing cropped up during testing.
